# why do I have to tell children to display flex when I already set the parent to flex?

Tags: css, parent-child, flexbox

for example if the .nav-flex is the parent why arent my flex stylings appearing for my child anchor elements. I have to DISPLAY: FLEX on the child anchor element to make it appear flex.

(parent )

```
.nav-flex  {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
```

(child)  /*i have to insert display: flex down here for flex to work*/

```
a {
  list-style-type: none;
  text-decoration: none;      
  flex-grow: 1;
  justify-content: space-around;
 }
```

Comment: You shouldn't have to, is the child inheriting styles from something maybe?

Comment: Show us your HTML structure.

Comment: A jsfiddle would be best, please. That would be the quickest way for everyone here to try and debug your code.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/gomezs11/s15c08sr/

Answer (score 2):

The [flex layout box model](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#box-model) has two concepts:

- [Flex containers](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-containers)

  > A [***flex container***](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-container) is the box generated by an element with a
  >   computed [`display`](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css2/visuren.html#propdef-display) of [`flex`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#valdef-display-flex) or [`inline-flex`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#valdef-display-inline-flex).
- [Flex items](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-items)

  > In-flow children of a flex container are called [***flex items***](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-item)
  >   and are laid out using the flex layout model.

Therefore, `.nav-flex { display: flex }` makes the `.nav-flex` a flex container and makes the `a` inside flex items.

Since `a` are flex items, `flex-grow: 1` will make them grow to fill all the `.nav-flex`.

However, `justify-content` only applies to flex containers, so it won't work.

Instead, I think you want one of these (they are equivalent):

- Since the `a` flex items establish a new block formatting context for its contents, you can center its inline-level content using `text-align`:

  ```css
  .nav-flex  {
    display: flex;
  }
  a {
    flex-grow: 1;
    text-align: center;
  }
  ```

  ```html
  <nav class="nav-flex"><a>Home</a><a>About</a><a>Contact</a></nav>
  ```
- Remove the `flex-grow: 1` to prevent the `a` from growing, and use the `justify-content: space-around` on `.nav-flex` to align them properly:

  ```css
  .nav-flex  {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
  }
  ```

  ```html
  <nav class="nav-flex"><a>Home</a><a>About</a><a>Contact</a></nav>
  ```
- Make the `a` flex items so that their text content will be wrapped in a flex item, and align it with `justify-content`:

  ```css
  .nav-flex  {
    display: flex;
  }
  a {
    flex-grow: 1;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center; /* Or space-around */
  }
  ```

  ```html
  <nav class="nav-flex"><a>Home</a><a>About</a><a>Contact</a></nav>
  ```